# Phonegap CLI builds for Android not showing splash screens

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

The Phonegap CLI documentation on the subject of Splashscreens and Icons suggests the following

> SplashScreen (string, defaults to splash): The name of the file minus its extension in the res/drawable directory. Various assets must share this common name in various subdirectories.

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="mySplash"/>
```

I configured my Phonegap CLI project as follows

```
project folder
|
res
  |
  ---port-ldpi.png
  |
  ---land-ldpi.png
  |
  --- ...
  |
  --- land-xhdpi.png
```

With that done I wrote up my project level config.xml file

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="12000"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>        
<splash src="res/port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
<splash src="res/land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
```

I then issued a `phonegap build android --release -d >> /tmp/result.txt` and examined the output in `/tmp/result.txt`.  I showed the following lines

```
copying image from /path/to/my/project/res/port-ldpi.png to     
/path/to/my/project/platforms/android/res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png

copying image from /path/to/my/project/res/land-ldpi.png to     
/path/to/my/project/platforms/android/res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png

.....

copying image from /path/to/my/project/res/land-xhdpi.png to     
/path/to/my/project/platforms/android/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png
```

Finally, I examined the generated APK by opening it in 7-zip.  In the `res` folder I found the following

```
drawable-port-ldpi-v4/screen.png
drawable-land-ldpi-v4/screen.png
...
drawable-land-xhdpi-v4/screen.png
```

The images beign the ones I supplied in my `/project/res` folder.  Finally, I checked the output to ensure that it was terminating with a `Command finished with error code 0:` line.

I then installed my application and ran it - no splash screen.

For good measure - though it makes little sense as a requirement - I retried the above after wrapping the splash & icon bits of the config.xml file in a

```
<platform name='android'>


</platform>
```

section - it made no difference.  The strange thing is that icons assigned in precisely the same way work perfectly.  I wanted to be sure that I was in fact supplying a splash screen for the resolution of my Huwaei Holly phone where I was testing it all so I used slightly different icon images.  The installation displayed the XHDPI icon so by rights when the app starts up it should display the XHDPI splash screen

This is a frequently discussed subject but I fail to see that I am doing something wrong here.

For completeness I should mention

- Phonegap CLI version : 5.3.6
- Tested on Honor Holly, Android version 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the answer for the benefit of anyone running into this thread.  The Cordova/Phonegap CLI documentation on the subject of splashscreens is very confusing.  Here are a few tips to help you along

- When you build the `config.xml` file you need to specify the locations of the various splashscreen images in the format `<splash src="res/{$name}.9.png" density="{$name}"/>`. The `.9.` is optional - use if if you are using 9 patch images
- You also need to have the line `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>`.  This is invariant.  Contrary to what the documentation seems to imply you have no choice over the value - `screen` and only `screen` will work.
- The original location of the images does not matter - it is best to place it in a folder inside the project folder, `res` in my case.  If you place it inside the `www` folder you end up with two copies of your image - one of which is never used.
- When Phonegap CLI builds your project it will copy your images to `platforms/android/res/drawable-port|land-??dpi-v4`.  I am not sure why `v4` but that is the wya it is.  It is these images that are used to show the splash screen
- **most important of all** On the Android splash screens do not show up at startup automatically.  For them to show up you must do two things

  1. Include the `cordova-plugin-splashscreen` plugin in your project
  2. Call navigator.splashscreen.show() - typically from the `deviceReady` event

Finally, to control the duration of the splash display you need to specify `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="..."/>` where the value is in milliseconds.

It would help a lot of developers if the Cordova documentation had the grace to mention that on the Android the splashscreen does not display automatically.